# How to store multiple data in isolated storage setting in wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to store multiple name in Isolated storage.And i use this code for store multopple storage

```
if (!setting.Contains("CityDetail"))
            {

                  setting.Add("CityDetail", cityname);

            }
            else 
            {
                setting["CityDetail"] = cityname;


                           }
            setting.Save();
```

But it gives only last added value,h=So how can i fetch all the data base value?

Answer (score 2):

You can use these function to store your objects in phoneapplication state

```
 public static void SaveState(string key, object value)
    {
        if (phoneApplicationPage.State.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            phoneApplicationPage.State.Remove(key);
        }

        phoneApplicationPage.State.Add(key, value);
    }

  public static object LoadState(this PhoneApplicationPage phoneApplicationPage, string key)
    {
        if (phoneApplicationPage.State.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return phoneApplicationPage.State[key];
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Edit-Using isolatedsettings

```
   public void SaveCompositeObject()
   {
      var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
      Person person= new City { Name = "Alex", Age= "21" };
      settings.Add("person", person);
   }

  public class Person
  {
     public string Name
     {
       get;
       set;
     }

    public string Age
    {
      get;
      set;
    }
}
```

retrieving data

```
 Person person1;
 settings.TryGetValue<Person>("person", out person11);
```

Comment: :thaks but i want do with use of isolated storage setting so how i can i do?

Comment: :thanks but this for one form only and i want to retrive data in another form.Actully i store data in first form button click and retrive data in second form load event.

Comment: U can do that using IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings. Refer this for more info http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage-store-data-in-isolatedstoragesettings

Comment: :thanks again but this is only for add one data ans i have multiple data so its problem and this is for one form only and i wants to retrive data in second form